# nginx config - negative condition

Tags: nginx-config

I make HTTP authorization in nginx config for all files, exclude index.php:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/site;
    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location ~ /(?!index.php) {
        auth_basic "Unauthorized";
        auth_basic_user_file /var/www/site/htpasswd;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
        }
}
```

As a result, nginx instead of executing PHP files, begins to give them to download. Without `location ~ /(?! index.php)` - files are normally executed.

How to make a negative condition correctly?